# Pi 400: unable to start Minecraft Pi

Tags: minecraft

Not able to start minecraft pi on my raspberry pi 400. Here is the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ minecraft-pi 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  10 (XF86VidModeSwitchToMode)
  Value in failed request:  0x378
  Serial number of failed request:  137
  Current serial number in output stream:  139
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had this error before and from my understanding this error seems to pop up, when you have a HD Monitor and the wrapper of minecraft-pi tries to start full-screen session on 2k+ Resoloution. There is a modded version [GitHub](https://github.com/MCPI-Revival/minecraft-pi-reborn) here. Maybe you can try this. There is also a thread on the [Raspberry Pi Forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=249140) which goes a little more indepth if you want to debug it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).